# Is it possible to clone a machine by "restoring" the backup of the existing machine to the new machine?

Tags: 12.04, backup, clone, file-server

I am wondering if the following is possible and exactly how I should go about it:

1. I have machine 'A' (dual core i5 2.3 GHz) with Ubuntu 12.04LTS installed and configured just the way I like it.
2. I use a network drive to backup machine 'A' (using the ubuntu backup tool).
3. I also have a machine 'B' (quad core i5 3.2 GHz).
4. I am thinking of doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04LTS on machine 'B', and then using the backup utility on machine 'B' to restore the backups of machine 'A' on to 'B', thereby cloning machine 'A' on machine 'B'.

Is such a thing doable? Is there a cleaner and/or safer way for me to clone 'A' on 'B'?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A better way is to create ISO containing all software you need as described here [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](http://askubuntu.com/q/48535) . There was a software called remastersys (which is no longer being developed). It enabled to create a complete backup and create live media from it. However, I don't have knowledge for the backup tool (as mentioned in question) to help you. Maybe drive cloning would be best.

Comment: This doesn't really strike me as "an exact duplicate" of the linked question.